# SMTP service on Windows 2008 R2 Core

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, smtp, windows-server-core

I have setup a server with Windows 2008 R2 Core Web Edition. The question is, how can I install the IIS7 SMTP service? Or is SMTP missing in the Core editions?

Thank you

Comment: I haven't used Server Core, so I'm putting this as a comment rather than an answer, but have you tried `servermanagercmd -install SMTP-Server`?

Comment: Unfortunately servermanagercmd.exe is not available on core editions.

Comment: That's too bad:(

Answer (score 1):

I have come to the conclusion that the Microsoft SMTP service is not supported on the Core editions. I found this list:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-differentiated-features.aspx

But such a list cannot be found for the core editions, bad documentation.

I'll install a third party SMTP service.

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](http://www.evanclosson.com/devlog/windowsserver2008websmtp):

> I just started a migration to windows
>   server 2008 web edition an ran into a
>   bit of a headache. The SMTP server at
>   first appears to be missing even after
>   installing the SMTP feature.
>
> After
>   some digging it appears that it can't
>   be administered from within iis7
>   manager. However, it can be managed
>   from "**Internet Information Services
>   (IIS) 6.0 Manager**."

I'm not sure if this has been changed for R2.

Comment: I believe R2 comes with FTP 7, which *is* managed from within IIS7.  Plain 2008 had FTP 6 which used the IIS 6 manager.

Comment: @phoebus: FTP? Aren't we talking about SMTP?

Comment: Yeah, brain fart/acronym overload ;P